# CakePHP and suphp socket, connection reset by peer

Tags: php, linux, apache, cakephp

In my Linux server's logs I have this
record nearly every 5 minutes. I
couldn't find the reason for two weeks
and I would be very happy if you can
recommend me a way to diagnose the
problem.

My hosting company insists that the problem is within my codes. I use CakePHP 2.2. But I couldn't find anything that causes this problem.

Records are inside error_log file. I use php
5.3.8 and litespeed. 2012-09-03 16:01:28.399 [INFO]
[95.7.223.91:63814-0#APVH_example.com
connection to [/tmp/lshttpd/
APVH_example.com_Suphp.sock. 781]
on request #151, confirmed, 0,
associated process: 845244, running: 0, error: Connection reset by peer!

Answer (score 1):

See below URL i think solve you problem:

http://www.litespeedtech.com/support/forum/showthread.php?t=6125

Let me know if not solved your problem.

**UPDATE**

You able to change any PHP settings via .htaccess with the same success. If you want to turn off 'Zend Guard' add following line in .htaccess file.

Code:

```
php_value zend_optimizer.optimization_level = 0
```

see below URL:-

http://forums.zend.com/viewtopic.php?f=57&t=7063

http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=947413

Comment: This seems like the problem. But my hosting company doesn't allow me to disable Zend Guard. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You able to change any PHP settings via .htaccess with the same success. If you want to turn off 'Zend Guard' add following line in .htaccess file.
Code:
php_value zend_optimizer.optimization_level = 0

Comment: Thank you for edited answer. I also have performance problems, wouldn't this adding make performance worse? To stop all optimizations.